# Add markers to maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Now that I know how to create a Maps and manage it. And that I can find information in my database (Retrofit and PHP API).

I would like to add markers to my map. To do this, I request my database and after passing through Retrofit, I retrieve a list of "Marker" objects that have two basic data for the moment: Longitude and latitude. This list is created in my MainActivity.

The problem is that I don't know how to pass this list in my class that manages the map.
For the moment I have tried by creating a Setter that passes the value table. The problem is that to generate markers, I can only do it in my `OnMapReady()`. But it's too early. By the time I enter `onMapReady()` my list is not set yet...

Basically I'm wondering how to add markers after an `onMapReady()`?

My MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.e("API_Test", "Message test");

        //BDD
        bddRequest githubService = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(bddRequest.ENDPOINT)
                .build()
                .create(bddRequest.class);
        githubService.listMarqueurs("API_REST",new Callback<List<Marqueur>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Marqueur> marqueur, Response response) {
                DisplayRepos(marqueur);

                int i = 0;
                while(i<marqueur.size())`enter code here`
                {
                    Log.e(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(marqueur.get(i).getLong()));
                    i++;
                }

                MapsFragment mapInitial = new MapsFragment(marqueur);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.e("API_Test","ERROR ! ");
            }
        });
    }

    public void DisplayRepos(List<Marqueur> marqueur) {
        Log.e("nombre de dépots : ", String.valueOf(+marqueur.size()));
    }
}
```

My MapsFragment.java:

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback
    {
        private List<Marqueur> tousLesMarqueurs;

        public MapsFragment() { }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
            final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(48.8534100, 2.3488000)).title("Paris").snippet("is beautiful !"));

            /*int i = 0;
            while(i<tousLesMarqueurs.size())
            {
                Log.e(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(tousLesMarqueurs.get(i).getLong()));
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(tousLesMarqueurs.get(i).getLati(), tousLesMarqueurs.get(i).getLong())));
                i++;
            }*/

        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

Comment: maps will be ready on its creation  so once you get the response set the marker

Answer (score 1):

In your MapsFragment, create an attribute `Map myMap`. And set it in `onMapReady()`.
Then in your setter create the markers.

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback
{

    private List<Marqueur> tousLesMarqueurs;
    private GoogleMap myMap;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        myMap = googleMap;

    }

    public void setMarkers( List<Marqueur> markers){
       tousLesMarqueurs = markers;
       int i = 0;
          while(i<tousLesMarqueurs.size())
          {
              myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(tousLesMarqueurs.get(i).getLati(), tousLesMarqueurs.get(i).getLong())));
              i++;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to also check if map is ready in setMarkers()